# How to use matplotlib to plot pyspark sql results for each row?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, pyspark

I have a table in hive which i am using to create a dataframe. The column of the table are :

[mer_name,year,month,sum_qty,sum_ln,sum_orders]

I want to plot a graph which will have sum_orders of all mer_name month wise.
something like this:

https://assets.digitalocean.com/articles/eng_python/pandas/name_plot-m-list.png

I tried with matplotlib but i am not able to plot.

code :

```
dataDF=sqlContext.sql("select * from db.testtable where year = 
                      2015")
pdDF = dataDF.toPandas()
ax=pdDF.plot(x=['mer_name','month'], y='sum_orders', 
               rot=45)
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('demo.pdf')
```

Also tried by making pivot table but it didn't work for me.

code:

```
 df=pd.pivot_table(pdDF,index= 
                    ["mer_name","year","month"],values= 
                    ["sum_orders"])
 ax=df.plot(rot=45)
 fig = ax.get_figure()
 fig.savefig('pivot')
```

please help.

thanks in advance